# Add pushpin on Tap bing map control - windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I want to ask you, if is good solution to add pushpin when user tap on screen? I make it so, when user tap on screen so pushpin is added with address. Is it another solution, how to add pushpin on certain position without tapping?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution could be to use the Hold event instead of the tap event. In that way, you will be sure that the user want to do something where they tap.

You can go [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to see more information about the maps control.

Hope it help !